# Closures and Events

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, closures, toggle

I am learning JavaScript.
I was practicing applying closures but I got stuck and am not able to find the issue with my code.

```js
function change_greeting() {
  let on_or_off = 1;
  return function button() {
    if (on_or_off) {
      document.getElementById("demo") = "Hello";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demo") = "Goodbye";
    }
  }
}
const click = change_greeting();
```

```html
<button onclick=click()>Click Me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I tried a similar example without mixing it up with events, at that time it succeeded. I am not sure as to what change I must bring to my code.

Comment: Some minor things to look at `on_or_off` never changes. `click=change_greeting()` calls the function and `click` will be undefined.

Comment: You need to toggle `on_or_off` by using one of: pre-increment and [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder); using [XOR assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR_assignment); or by using a boolean `on_or_off = !on_or_off ; // toggle boolean`. Also, use Element.textContent to change an element's text. More in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- to toggle `on_or_off` 1,0,1,0,etc... use the [Remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) after an increment: `on_or_off = ++on_or_off % 2` or simply using `XOR` assignment `on_or_off ^= 1;`
- avoid the use of `on`* inline attribute handlers. Use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead
- use [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) when you want to output a string to an Element's content

```js
const elDemo = document.getElementById("demo");
const elBtn = document.getElementById("btn");

function change_greeting() {

  let on_or_off = 1;
  
  return function () {
    if (on_or_off) {
      elDemo.textContent = "Hello";
    } else {
      elDemo.textContent = "Goodbye";
    }
    
    on_or_off = ++on_or_off % 2; // loop 0,1,0,1,...
  }
}

const click = change_greeting(); // call and return closure fn
elBtn.addEventListener("click", click);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<span id="demo"></span>
```

And here's the example using XOR assignment:

```js
const elDemo = document.getElementById("demo");
const elBtn = document.getElementById("btn");

const change_greeting = ()  => {
  let isOn = 1;
  return () => {
    elDemo.textContent = isOn ? "Hello" : "Goodbye";
    isOn ^= 1; // toggle 0,1,0,1...
  }
};

const click = change_greeting();
elBtn.addEventListener("click", click);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<span id="demo"></span>
```

For completeness, instead of using integers `1,0,1,0...` you could instead use a boolean variable and switch it using `isOn = !isOn`

```js
const elDemo = document.querySelector("#demo");
const elBtn = document.querySelector("#btn");

const change_greeting = () => {
  let isOn = true;
  return () => {
    elDemo.textContent = isOn ? "Hello" : "Goodbye";
    isOn = !isOn; // toggle boolean
  }
};

elBtn.addEventListener("click", change_greeting());
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<span id="demo"></span>
```

and, as you can see in the latest example, there's no need to store the closure in a `click` variable. If not used elsewhere you can simply call it within the click handler `.addEventListener("click", change_greeting());`

Additionally (as seen in this examples), you can replace the 5 lines of `if/else` with a readable, well known and loved [Ternary (conditional) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) `statement ? truthy : falsy`

Comment: nice to hear, happy coding! @ErvinRanjan

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite this

```js
    ...
    let on_or_off=1;
    return function button()
    {
    if(on_or_off)
    ...
```

to this (add changing the value to make toggle work):

```js
    ...
    let on_or_off=true;
    return function button()
    {
    on_or_off = !on_or_off;
    if(on_or_off)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing the toggle logic on a `boolean` value and making more out of the advantage of dealing with a created closure, the OP's example code could be streamlined to something much more readable as ...

```js
function createGreetingsToggleHandler(contentNode) {
  let isGoodbye = true;

  return function () {
    contentNode.textContent = isGoodbye && 'Hello' || 'Goodbye';
    isGoodbye = !isGoodbye;
  }
}
document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener(
    'click',
    createGreetingsToggleHandler(
      document.querySelector('#greetings')
    )
  );
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
<p id="greetings"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Here, the issue encountering is related to a naming conflict with the variable name "click". In JavaScript, there is already a global method called click() that is associated with clicking on HTML elements. When you use the variable name "click" for your closure function, it overrides the global click() method, causing conflicts and preventing the expected behavior.
2. You need to use innerHTML because the innerHTML property is used to get or set the HTML content inside an element.
3. To implement a toggle functionality, you can use the line on_or_off = !on_or_off; inside your code. This line will toggle the value of the on_or_off variable between true and false.

```js
function change_greeting() {
  let on_or_off = true;
  return function button() {
    if (on_or_off) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Goodbye";
    }
    on_or_off = !on_or_off;
  }
}
const closure = change_greeting();
```

```html
<button onclick="closure()">Click Me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```